# Quartz.net WithCronSchedule 'Illegal character after '?': |' c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cron, quartz.net

I am trying to schedule a job using the Quartz.NET package, but I cannot get it working. I tried the following code but I am getting an exception:

> Illegal character after '?': |

My schedule job should run twice a day. Once at noon (12:00) and once at midnight (00:00). Here are my `cron` expressions.

`0 0 0 * * ?`

`0 0 12 * * ?`

Here is the code:

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public async static void Start()
    {
        string noonJob = "0 0 0 * * ?";
        string midnightJob = "0 0 12 * * ?";
        string strCronExpression = noonJob + "|" + midnightJob;
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.Start().Wait();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJobClass>().WithIdentity("MyJobKey", "MyJobGroup").Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDescription("MyJobKey")
            .WithIdentity("MyJobKey", "MyJobGroup")
            .WithCronSchedule(strCronExpression)
            .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
            .WithPriority(1)
            .Build();

        bool isExists = scheduler.CheckExists(job.Key).Result;
        if (isExists)
        {
            await scheduler.RescheduleJob(new TriggerKey("MyJobKey", "MyJobGroup"), trigger);
        }
        else
        {
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is complaining about this:

```
string strCronExpression = noonJob + "|" + midnightJob;
```

which will produce the string

```
0 0 0 * * ? | 0 0 12 * * ?
```

as the cron expression.

Where did you get the idea you can string 2 cron expressions together like that? I can't find (from an admittedly brief search) any evidence that it's a valid syntax. The error is clearly telling you that it doesn't understand the information you're providing.

Anyway if you just want it to run twice daily (midnight and noon) I'm pretty sure you can give that instruction in one single cron expression. I think you can use the expression

```
0 0 0,12 * * ?
```

to get that schedule.

Of course if you want to define two totally different schedules which are not describable in a single expression), you'd probably need two entirely separate jobs (even if they execute the same command).

Comment: thank you for quick response, any suggestions on how to generate a single Cron expression from the multiple cron expression strings. I am using this jQuery plugin [jquery-cron](http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/) but it is not sufficient to my requirement.

Comment: it seems quartz.net support multiple CronExpression in one string [https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/252](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/252)

Comment: @sridharnetha In the answer I've already given you an example of a suitable single expression for your needs...did you try it? You don't really need a cron-generating tool, you just need to understand the spec.

Comment: @sridharnetha "it seems quartz.net support multiple CronExpression in one string "...where in that GitHub link does it say it's supported? The OP in that post asks if it's possible to add it, and the response says they aren't going to do it. No indication of any support for it, and none planned either. Hence you get an error when you try to do it.

Comment: @sridharnetha what the second post in that link _does_ show you is an expression to convert a `|`-delimited string of cron expressions into a list of Trigger objects, which are all then applied to the schedule. That's a reasonable workaround. It does _not_ provide direct support for the `|`-delimited string expression to be placed inside a single Trigger, which is what you're doing. So, you can use that workaround if you like, but in this specific case you can achieve your requirement with a single Cron expression as per my answer, so it's unnecessary